# How to control spinning of UIActivityIndicatorView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have seen many apps which can control `spinning` `rate` of `UIActivityIndicatorView`.
One example is `Instagram`, while refreshing latest feed when you drag `UITableView` down slowly the `UIACtivityIndicatorView` loads slowly one petal at a time.
Just wondering how is this achievable with native `UIActivityIndicatorView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm guessing you're using a `UITableView` (`tableView`). I think it's native what you're trying to achieve.

You have to use a `UIRefreshControl`.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIRefreshControl *refreshControl;
```

And use it like this in `viewDidLoad` of your viewController for example

```
// The refresh view
self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc]init];
self.refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.refreshControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.tableView addSubview:refreshControl];
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshWhatYouWant:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Now if you pull to refresh your `tableView` slowly, you'll have the `UIActivityIndicatorView` loading one petal at a time.

Hope it helps.

Tom

Comment: drink on me...  Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use custom control ....As far as I know  `UIActivityIndicatorView` doesn't provide you any API for controlling speed of indicator